# Manage screen brightness in node.js

Tags: node.js, screen

I'm willing to be able to manage laptop screen brightness using code in my node.js app. Do you know how to do so ?

If there is a need to develop multiple ways to do it for compatibility (Windows, OSX, Linux...), that's not a problem and if you know how for any platform, answer is welcomed :)

Thanks !

Comment: Just found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/brightness

Comment: Yeah I would like not to use a module and develop it myself, guess I'll juste have to look at this code